# garamond-libre and small caps

Tags: accents, font-encodings, characters, small-caps, garamond

I want to use the Garamond font provided by the `garamondlibre` package. Unfortunately, it appears that the small caps cause some issues: One minor issue is that `\textsc{ff}` produces an ff-ligature that uses the usual lowercase letters; I could fix this by disabling ligatures for scshaped text (see below). However, the following minimal example involving the character ‘ü’

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{shape=sc}
\usepackage{garamondlibre}

\begin{document}
\textsc{Aufführung}
\end{document}
```

produces the following result:

[image: \textsc{Aufführung}]

Theoretically, I can cheat by using the `amsmath` package and instead write

```
\textsc{Auff$\ddot{\textsc{u}}$hrung}
```

This actually looks quite nice (even though the dots are not fully centered):

[image: \textsc{Auff$\ddot{\textsc{u}}$hrung}]

I could also use the `OT1`-option for the `fontenc` package, but this produces way too high dots:

[image]

Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: The fonts were converted from the OpenType font, that has several problems with small caps: it only has the unadorned letters so the accented ones come from the standard letters.

Comment: That’s unfortunate, I really like the font! Is there a quick way to add the missing glyphs to the font (even if it’s just for the OpenType files; then I could use them with `lualatex`)? I guess that requires more than a few lines of LaTeX code?

Comment: Short answer: no. Unless you create in some way the accented glyphs belonging to the `smcp` feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many other fonts for `pdflatex`, GaramondLibre is obtained by converting an OpenType font with `otftotfm` (as stated in the documentation of `garamondlibre`.

If we run the following code with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{garamondlibre}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Aufführung}

\end{document}
```

we see that the problem is exactly the same:

[image]

Small caps are only available for the unadorned Latin Letters, I'm afraid. The automatic conversion from the OpenType font does the same as the `smcp` OpenType feature: it queries the specific table for a variant glyph and, upon not finding it, the normal glyph is returned.

Sorry, but there's no chance of making it work unless the OpenType font is fixed by adding at least the most common letters with diacritics and the conversion to legacy TFM fonts is redone.

Just for completeness, I add the output of

```
Aufführung

\textsc{Aufführung}
```

first with `garamondlibre`

[image]

and then with `ebgaramond`

[image]

In either case, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` was used.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a one-off, rather than extending the  font., you could break the ff ligature and position the accent over a normal u.  As this is using the Unicode combining accent not a classic TeX `\accent` it will still cut and paste correctly as `AUFFÜHRUNG`

With lualatex:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{garamondlibre}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Aufführung}

\textsc{Auf\/f\"{\/u\kern-.05em}̈\kern.05em hrung}

\end{document}
```